# Same log4j2.xml for different java processes with separate log level

Tags: java, xml, log4j2

## Problem

I want to standardize my `log4j2.xml` setup for several Java processes that I run on different linux servers. My hard condition: a single `log4j2.xml` for all servers.

Sometimes it is needed that I change my `loglevel` from `INFO` to `DEBUG` while the Java process is running. You can do this by changing the `logLevel` in the `log4j2.xml`, while you have `monitorInterval` configured.

However, this changes the `loglevel` of ALL processes that are running on that server! I need a solution that I can change the logLevel for a single process.

### My first try

I thought that I would move the logLevel to the properties. Suppose I have the `log4j2.xml` (as an example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %t %-5p %-32c{1} - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="${bundle:logger:logLevel}">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Next to this, I also have the file `logger.properties` on the classpath:

```
logLevel=INFO
```

Now when I change my `log4j2.xml` (by just adding a space somewhere) and updating this property file, the logging changes. However, as mentioned it changes the `logLevel` of ALL processes.

### What I want

I want to be able to have a `logger.properties` that looks like this:

```
process1LogLevel=INFO
process2LogLevel=DEBUG
```

And then something in the `log4j2.xml` that configures this property dynamically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %t %-5p %-32c{1} - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="${bundle:logger:<something based on the process name>}">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

However, this "flexible" property doesn't really work. Do you have any idea for a solution?

### Note

If you have a different idea that looks a little bit different but achieves my goals, that is also fine! Any out-of-the-box solution is always appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. You can nest properties. If you specify `-Dname=process1` for example, you can use it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="1">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="process1">DEBUG</Property>
        <Property name="process2">INFO</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %t %-5p %-32c{1} - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="${${sys:name}}">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```